# Reset imported js file when back button is pressed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, import, export

I have question about how to reset the imported js file when user click on the back button and click forward button.

So for example

a.js file (where it will display the data) will import getData function data.js file.
data.js file will send the data to the a.js file.

Example data for data.js file below

```
const data = [
  {
    id: "bee"
    bool: true
  },
  {
    id: "spider"
    bool: false
  }
]

const getData = () => {
   const tempData = data;
   // do the logic here and return
   return tempData;
}


export default {
  getData 
};
```

so lets say I change the data from the a.js file using the getData function after importing the data.js file. The data still holds the previous data. So if I change the id spider bool to true, it will still holds the value of true when user clicks on the back button and comeback to the page again with forward button.

I tried to do the useeffect to reset the data but that did not work...
Is there a way to reset the data.js file?

Answer (score 1):

You should send a clone of the data out by doing this:

```
const getData = () => {
   const tempData = [...data]; //creating a new array here breaks reference to the original
   // do the logic here and return
   return tempData;
}
```

and then create a setData function that will be in charge of updating the data within data.js if you ever want the changes to be reflected within that file.

Edit: create a restore state method that you call when you need to set the data back to the original:

```
const restoreState = () => {
   data.splice(0);
   data.push(...[
     {
       id: "bee"
       bool: true
     },
     {
       id: "spider"
       bool: false
     }
   ]);
}
```

or simply reassign the value of `data` if you choose to define `data` with `let` instead of `const`.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for replying to my question. I did tried that option by using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)); but the problem is that everytime when i call that function, it will reset the data to new. So i only want it to get the default data once when the user click on the back or forward button. Also, I tried the spread to copy the data but it still got the previous data so i used the json.parse(json.stringify()). Not sure why though..

Comment: No problem, I've edited the answer with another suggestion following your comment